# Need help to setup dynamic values in a Wysiwyg Editor

Tags: variables, wysiwyg

1) We are creating dynamic questionnaires in which each questionnaire has different number of questions and answers.

2) After user fills the questionnaire, we are saving all the entries in a database

3) After that, we want to create a word document.

4) In word document, we want to set a logic which allows the user to write the content of word document along with some dynamic values.

**Example content of Sample Word Document:**

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

Name of person: Eshban

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample

**Document Content Ends**

Now in the above example, we have some sample content "**This is a sample text**" with dynamic value i.e. **Name of the person : Eshban**

As user is writing this content in WYSIWYG editor or in a text area, I want a setup a way 
to set these dynamic values i.e Name of the person : Eshban

Any idea that how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
      $('#container').val($('#container').val().replace('Eshban','Name:'));
```

This code will replace **Eshban** with **Name**